# Is there an R equivalent for the excel countif function?

Tags: r, countif

I have 4 columns and they are all unique barcodes, however it is possible that a barcode from column A (V1) occurs in column B (V2) or C (V3) or D (V4).

Column A (V1) is the original barcode.

**I want to see whether a barcode in column A occurs in any of the other columns**. Just a simple 1 (yes) or 0 (no).

In excel i would use the "countif" then select the cel and then the range. However I cant use excel because the dataset exceeds a million rows. So im using Rstudio which i am very unexperienced in.

The barcode dataframe is called `df.correct`.

I have tried:

```
df.correct$outcome <- if (df.correct$V1 == df.correct$V2) {
  1} else if (df.correct$V1 == df.correct$V3) {
  1} else if (df.correct$V1 == df.correct$V4) {
  1} else {0}
```

which gives:

````
Warning messages:
1: In if (df.correct$V1 == df.correct$V2) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (df.correct$V1 == df.correct$V3) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (df.correct$V1 == df.correct$V4) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.```
````

It has something to do with vectors? So i searched on stackoverflow and tried:

```
  if (a>0){
    a/sum(a)
  }
  else 1
}
```

This didnt work. Anybody that can help?

Comment: `with(df.correct, sum(V1 == V2 | V1 == V3 | V1 == V4))`?

Comment: `if` is a single-logical operator. That means that you can do a single true/false at a time; in your code, `df.correct$V1==df.correct$v2` is as long as there are rows in the frame, which fails. The vectorized version of `if` is `ifelse`, such as `with(df.correct, sum(ifelse(V1 == V2, 1, ifelse(V1 == V3, 1, ifelse(V1 == V4, 1, 0)))))`, but that is far less elegant and flexible, the use of the vector-OR `|` infix operator is much more flexible and controllable in this instance.

Comment: (The use of `with(df.correct, ...)` is purely for reduction of code here in comments; it works just as well with `sum(df.correct$V1 == df.correct$V2 | ...)`.)